# Translate module won't translate document

Tags: python

I am trying to translate an excerpt of a my country's law. First of all I extracted the part of the law I'm interested in (text between 1st article and 2nd article:

```
import re

with open("LISR.txt") as law:
original_text = law.read()
excerpt = re.findall(r'Article 1(.*?)Article 2',original_text,re.DOTALL)
```

If we print excerpt variable we got something like this:

```
['. Las personas físicas y las morales, están obligadas al pago del impuesto 
sobre la renta en los siguientes casos:']
```

So now we want to translate it, we import translation:

```
from translation import bing
print(bing(excerpt, dst = 'en'))
```

And we get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Rafael/PycharmProjects/untitled/mcparent 3.py", line 14, in <module>
print(bing(excerpt, dst = 'en'))
File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-
packages\translation\__init__.py", line 31, in bing
dst = dst, proxies = proxies)
File "C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-
packages\translation\main.py", line 33, in get
if r == '': raise TranslateError('No translation get, you may retry')
translation.exception.TranslateError: No translation get, you may retry
```

Which is wierd because if I try it translating "manually" it works like a charm:

```
 Input: print(bing('. Las personas físicas y las morales, están obligadas al pago del impuesto sobre la renta en los siguientes casos:', dst = 'en'))
 Output: . Natural persons and morals are obligated to pay the income tax in the following cases:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you printed `excerpt`, you got this, correct?

```
['. Las personas físicas y las morales, están obligadas al pago del impuesto 
sobre la renta en los siguientes casos:']
```

Notice the brackets? `[]`, it indicates it's a list, so you probably should do this, since, for your second working example, it's not a `list`, but a `str`:

```
from translation import bing
print(bing(excerpt[0], dst = 'en'))
```